# rails sorcery user_mapping possible values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, external, sorcery

I'm using Sorcery gem in Rails and what to know what are the possible values user_info_mapping for facebook.

config.facebook.user_info_mapping = {}

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It expects a hash, where

- **keys** are symbols of **attributes in your `User` (or whatever) model** (like `:email`)
- **values** are names of **attributes received from Facebook**, documented [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user) (like `"name"`).

Example [here](https://github.com/NoamB/sorcery/blob/master/lib/generators/sorcery/templates/initializer.rb#L121).

Comment: Thanks for the link to documentation. That's what I'm looking for.